# React Native Picker won't display dynamically loaded options

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, picker

Hey I'm trying to create a Picker that shows options that are loaded first from my backend via an API. I want to load an array and then use this array to populate my picker options. The problem is that the Picker won't display any dynamically loaded data, although it will display static data. Even if the data loads after the picker renders, it should re-render with the new data, but it doesn't.

**I'm using this library for the Picker because of an issue that the React Native Picker has on Android : https://github.com/sleighdogs/react-native-android-native-picker**

(Issue : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15556 )

I'm loading the items for my picker from an API, but they don't appear when they are loaded. Nor do they appear when I load them initially.

This is how I load them:

```
var temp_regions= [];
              for( var i in response.data )
              {
                temp_regions.push({ 'value': response.data[i].id.toString(), 'label': response.data[i].province})
              }
this.setState({ region_options: temp_regions } );
```

And the result is that region_options contains one element:

```
{value: "1", label: "Masr el gedida"}
```

And this is my function that renders the Picker :

```
renderPicker() {
    if( this.state.region_options.length < 1 )
      {
        console.log('render dummy');
        return <Picker
          prompt = 'Regions'
          selectedValue={this.state.region}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({region: Number(itemValue) })}
          items = {[{value: '0', label: 'Loading'}]}
          >
            <View><Text><Text style={{'fontWeight':'bold'}}>Selected value:</Text> {this.state.region}</Text></View>
        </Picker>
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('render real');
        return <Picker
          prompt = 'Regions'
          selectedValue={this.state.region}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({region: Number(itemValue) })}
          items = {this.state.region_options}
          >
            <View><Text><Text style={{'fontWeight':'bold'}}>Selected value:</Text> {this.state.region}</Text></View>
        </Picker>
      }
  }
```

The Picker never displays the content of this.state.region_options unless they are set statically before running the app. No errors show up. 'render dummy' is printed initially, which is fine, then when the data loads, 'render real' is printed but the Picker doesn't actually change it's contents.

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15556#issuecomment-360181487)?

Comment: I've seen it but I haven't tried it. I don't understand what the difference between that and the normal implementation of Picker is to be honest. Is it the onChange() ? or is that related to redux-form?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(Props){
    super(Props);
    this.state={
      selectedRegion:null,
    }
  }

  getItems() {
    var items = [];    
    var region = [{value: "1", label: "Masr el gedida"}];   
    for (i=0;i<region.length;i++) {
      console.log("region : " + JSON.stringify(region))
      items.push(<Picker.Item key ={region[i].value} value={region[i].value} label={region[i].label} />);
    }
    return items;    
  }
  render() {    
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedRegion}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ selectedRegion: itemValue })}>
          {this.getItems()}
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
```